# Slider "animation" in WPF?

Tags: wpf, animation, user-interface, slider

I have a button and a slider, when I press the button so do I want the slider to tick one step until it reach its maximum value.

However once I click the button, it sleeps a while and then shows the slider at the maximum value, without showing each tick. Why?

---

Here's my XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button x:Name="AnimationGoButton" Content="Go" />
    <Slider x:Name="AnimationSlider" TickFrequency="1" TickPlacement="BottomRight" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Width="200" Maximum="20" Value="0" />
</StackPanel>
```

And here's my code behind:

```
Private Sub AnimationGoButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles AnimationGoButton.Click
    While (Me.AnimationSlider.Value < Me.AnimationSlider.Maximum)
        Me.AnimationSlider.Value += 1
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    End While
End Sub
```

I have tried to use a dynamic resource, but the result was the same.

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <sys:Double x:Key="AnimationSliderValue">0</sys:Double>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then I changed the Value for the slider in XAML to:

```
Value="{DynamicResource AnimationSliderValue}"
```

And change the code behind to:

```
While (Me.AnimationSlider.Value < Me.AnimationSlider.Maximum)
    Resources("AnimationSliderValue") += 1
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
End While
```

The result was the same. When I press the button the UI doesn't update until it has reached the Maximum value.

How do I create this "animation" I want for the slider?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx) for animations.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="userControl">
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    <Storyboard x:Key="SlideUpAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RangeBase.Value)" Storyboard.TargetName="slider1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="10"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="SlideDownAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RangeBase.Value)" Storyboard.TargetName="slider1">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SlideUpAnimation}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button x:Name="btnSlideDown" Click="btnSlideDown_Click" Content="Slide Down" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Slider Height="23" x:Name="slider1" Width="100" />
    <Button x:Name="btnSlideUp" Click="btnSlideUp_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Slide Up" />
</StackPanel>
```

And then start the storyboards on button clicks:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSlideUp_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)this.FindResource("SlideUpAnimation"));
    }

    private void btnSlideDown_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)this.FindResource("SlideDownAnimation"));
    }
}
```

Note: You need to add the PresentationFramework.dll in your project references in order to access the Storyboard class in code.

**Update per comment below**

You want to increment the Slider.Value by whole integers only using animations. Since the target value type is Double, the animation calculates and applies double values to the target, based on the animation frame rate. (The animation frame rate is 60 fps by default, but even if you did reduce it, that still may or may not give you even values depending on the beginning value).  I don't know of any ways to tell the DoubleAnimation to use even values only. There exists an Int32Animation class but you cannot apply that to Slider.Value which is of type double.

Here's my hacky solution (which I don't quite like): Add a SliderIntValue (Int32) dependency property to the parent (e.g. MainWindow or maybe your viewmodel) and bind it to the Slider.Value using two-way binding. The Binding class will magically take care of the type conversion. Then apply the animations to the SliderIntValue instead of the slider itself:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="userControl">
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    <Storyboard x:Key="SlideUpAnimation">
        <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="SliderIntValue" Storyboard.TargetName="userControl">
            <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="10"/>
        </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="SlideDownAnimation">
        <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="SliderIntValue" Storyboard.TargetName="userControl">
            <EasingInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
        </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button x:Name="btnSlideDown" Click="btnSlideDown_Click" Content="Slide Down" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Slider Height="23" x:Name="slider1" Width="100" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Value="{Binding SliderIntValue, ElementName=userControl, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button x:Name="btnSlideUp" Click="btnSlideUp_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Slide Up" />
    <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider1}" Margin="20,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And here's the dependency property added to the MainWindow class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderIntValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SliderIntValue",
                typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSlideUp_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)this.FindResource("SlideUpAnimation"));
    }

    private void btnSlideDown_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginStoryboard((Storyboard)this.FindResource("SlideDownAnimation"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this storyboard to use the "TickFrequency="1""-setting? Right now so does it animate smoothly, which looks nice, but I need to check when it hits "1", "2" and not "0.1116" and so on.

Comment: Hello guys i want to do the same thing with the Ticks but i am doing the animation without bindings but with code behind, how can i do it? What do i have to set? i have something like this but i doent work --> Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_DoubleAnimation, new PropertyPath(SliderIntValueProperty));